# No implicit new line at the end of python statement

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python.I just learnt that python implicitly prints a new line at the end of each print statement.Which has been true for most of the statements that I have tried.

```
number = 23 

guess = int(input("Enter an integer"))

if number == guess:
    print('guessed the number correctly')
else:
    print('That was an incorrect guess')
```

When I executed the above code a popwindow came up and I put in 23.This is the output that I got.

```
Enter an integerguessed the number correctly
```

I am not using the standard python but using an online python IDE called pythonfiddle.

Comment: Where did you execute this?

Comment: Under normal circumstances, there would be `23` and a newline between "Enter an integer" and "guessed the number correctly", because under normal circumstances, you would have typed your input there.

Comment: The code works as expected in terminal / cmd shell.
See [the screencast](http://asciinema.org/a/7255).

Comment: it is probably my mistake.I am using a website (google chrome app) called pythonfiddle.

Comment: @liv2hak: If you edit that information into the question, it'll make a good question even better for future searchers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `print` function has an implicit newline (unless you use the `end` keyword argument to tell it to do otherwise). The [`input`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) itself explicitly does not:

> If the *prompt* argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline…

When you're running Python in a terminal, `input` works by reading a line of input from that terminal, so when you type `23` and hit `return`, the terminal echoes that back, including the newline.

If you're running Python under an IDE-like environment (whether IDLE, Visual Studio, or an online IDE like [Python Fiddle](http://pythonfiddle.com)), it may implement `input` by, say, popping up a dialog box for you to type your input into. In that case, your input appears in that box, not in the output, so there is no newline.

Most such IDEs won't show the prompt on output either—instead, they'll usually show it in the dialog box. But there's no rule saying they *can't* print the prompt to the output instead (and, in fact, the wording of the documentation quoted above implies that maybe they should). So, what Python Fiddle is doing to you is perfectly reasonable.

If you want your code to handle it nicely, you could try to detect the environment and print your own newline in that case. I'm not sure *how* to distinguish that site vs. IDLE vs. a regular terminal (I noticed that `sys.stdin.isatty()` and `sys.stdout.isatty()` both return `True` on Fiddle…), but you may be able to find it by searching their documentation.